# Gap between an even integer and the next smaller prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I am desparately searching for a case that would skip the following conjecture (a variation of the Goldbach conjecture):

"Let $N$ an even integer, $P$ the very next prime smaller than $N$, and $D=N-P$. Then $D$ is always a prime. (Except $D=1$)"

Can anybody help me with a case to reject this conjecture?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$122$ is even, and it is between $113$ and $127$.  The difference, $122-113$, is $9$, definitely composite.

How I searched: primes greater than two are odd, so the difference between an even number and a prime is odd, so what is the smallest composite odd number?  Then, the search was for a pair of neighboring primes at least nine apart.

Answer (score 16):

The counterexample of Kyle Miller solve the problem, but we can say more. Since we can take [prime gaps abitrarily large](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095948/confusion-on-the-proof-that-there-are-arbitrarily-large-gaps-between-successive), we have that exists infinite even numbers such that $D$ is composite.

Comment: How does the existence of arbitrarily large prime gaps imply that the difference $D$ between an even number and its immediately preceding prime number is composite infinitely often?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Beacuse you can choose an even number $N$ such that its distance with the next prime smaller than $N$ is an odd composite number.

Comment: What I know, is that I can choose an even number $N$ such that its distance to the immediately preceding prime is as huge as I want. For example I can choose that $N$ such that the difference to the preceding prime is greater than $10^{1000}$. How can I use that to assure the difference is non-prime?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Assume that the distance from $p_{n+1}$ and $p_{n}$ is greater than $10^{1000}$. Then consider $N=p_{n}+9$. It is an even number, the next smallest prime is $p_{n}$ and $D=9$. Now take $N=p_{n}+15$ and so on. And when you have considered all the possibilities, you can take a larger gaps between primes.

Comment: Ah, of course, I do not know why I did not see that before! We see that all odd numbers (including odd composite numbers) occur infinitely often as $D$.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini - For the statement in the answer itself, you don't need the full strength of the arbitrarily large prime gaps result, just that prime gaps $>9$ occur infinitely often. But you seem to even be showing that every odd composite occurs as $D$ for some choice of $N$.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Yes, you are right.